# Outlook 2013 VSTO We can't complete this because we can't contact the server right now. Please try again later

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

We have an Outlook Add-in written using VSTO.

It has been running fine for months in **Outlook 2013** (*code migrated from Outlook 2010 version*) then today suddenly it starts to get an error trying to access the `Application.Session.CurrentUser` property after some windows updates were applied to the Exchange server.

When that property is accessed Outlook opens a login dialog, regardless of what is entered into the dialog Outlook will throw the error:

> "We can't complete this because we can't contact the server right now. Please try again later".

Up until today this caused no issue whatsoever and some of the users have no problems.

Were there any updates to exchange that may have changed some security settings for VSTO Addins in Outlook 2013?

Comment: It appears that the updates to the exchange server did not complete properly. reapplying the updates to the exchange server has corrected the issue.